# How to mock a constructor with a spy?

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockk, kotlin-exposed

I am currently trying to test my Exposed Kotlin code. I have a table that follows the form

```
object Foo: Table() {
   *parameters*
}
```

and a method that looks something like

```
fun addNewFoo(){
    Foo.insert { ... }
}
```

I'm testing `addNewFoo` and I want to verify the insert occurred, ideally using something like

```
verify { FooSpy.insert { ... } }
```

How do I mock the Foo table to be a spy so I can verify the call occurred, or what other approach should I take to verify this method being called?

Answer (score 0):

You can first mock your singleton `Foo` class using `mockkObject()` and then verify. Here is the code:

```kotlin
mockkObject(Foo) // mock the object
addNewFoo() // call function that we're testing
verify { Foo.insert(any()) } // verify
```

Comment: Thanks! Normally this would work great, but unfortunately since ```Foo``` is an Exposed table, it has some weird properties, and this doesn't work. The ```insert``` needs to be inside a transaction, which makes it harder to test

Answer (score 0):

There is discussion of ways to go about it: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/317

There seems to be no real intended way for testing but making small test tables in a test data base is the closest you can get.